# Storing joda datetime using slick, always stores UTC datetime

Tags: mysql, scala, jodatime, slick-2.0

I am actually having problems storing DateTime value in MySQL DB using slick,
I have a case class like this:

```
case class FacebookShares(
  var id: Int,
  var designID: Int,
  var shareOrgID: String,
  var sharerID: Int,
  var sharedLink: String,
  var sharedTimestamp: Instant,
  var sharedDatetime: DateTime,
  var modifiedTimestamp: Instant) {
  def this() = this(0, 0, "", 0, "", DateTime.now(DateTimeZone.forID("America/New_York")).toInstant, DateTime.now(DateTimeZone.forID("America/New_York")), DateTime.now.toInstant)
}
```

And its slick projection class:

```
class FacebookShareProjection(tag: Tag) extends Table[FacebookShares](tag, "facebook_shares_47") {
  def id: Column[Int] = column[Int]("id", O.PrimaryKey)
  def designID: Column[Int] = column[Int]("fs_design_id")
  def shareOrgID: Column[String] = column[String]("fs_share_org_id")
  def sharerID: Column[Int] = column[Int]("fs_sharer_id")
  def sharedLink: Column[String] = column[String]("fs_shared_link")
  def sharedTimestamp: Column[Instant] = column[Instant]("fs_shared_timestamp")
  def sharedDatetime: Column[DateTime] = column[DateTime]("fs_shared_datetime")
  def modifiedTimestamp: Column[Instant] = column[Instant]("fs_modified_timestamp")

  def * : ProvenShape[FacebookShares] = (id, designID, shareOrgID, sharerID, sharedLink, sharedTimestamp, sharedDatetime, modifiedTimestamp) <> (
    ((FacebookShares.apply _): (Int, Int, String, Int, String, Instant, DateTime, Instant) => FacebookShares).tupled,
    FacebookShares.unapply)

}
```

Now when I try insert data, the resultant date in the MySQL table shows timestamp of UTC timezone, when I have defined timezone for "America/New_York"

```
def store() = {
    val timestamp = DateTime.now(DateTimeZone.forID("America/New_York")).toInstant
    SQLDB.withSession { implicit session =>
      shareProjection += FacebookShares(0, 0, "", 0, "", timestamp, DateTime.now(DateTimeZone.forID("America/New_York")), DateTime.now.toInstant)
    }
  }
```

Why is the date being stored in UTC timezone rather then EST timezone

Comment: MySQL stores all the timestamps in UTC format, form the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/datetime.html): MySQL converts TIMESTAMP values from the current time zone to UTC for storage, and back from UTC to the current time zone for retrieval. (This does not occur for other types such as DATETIME.) By default, the current time zone for each connection is the server's time. The time zone can be set on a per-connection basis. As long as the time zone setting remains constant, you get back the same value you store.

Comment: So, when I retrieve back the time values from the table, I will receieve the time back in the timezone that my server is set for.
So, well now the problem is the timezone that my server follows is UTC, and I want datetime to be in EST zone, so what can be done?? I can't change my servers timezone.

Comment: You have to convert the timestamp to the user local format, there are some Jodatime functionality like `setDefaultTimezone` that can help you.

Comment: Umm, thats what I had been doing when using Riak, though didn't know that MySQL only allowed UTC. Thank you, @ende-neu